# Converting HTML page to PDF with a watermark image on each page in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to convert an HTML page to PDF and add a watermark image to each page using React. I'm currently using the html2pdf.js library, but I haven't been able to find the correct approach to add a watermark.

Here's the code I've tried so far:

```
import React from "react";
import html2pdf from "html2pdf.js";
import watermarkImg from "./watermark.png";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const handleExportToPdf = () => {
    const content = document.getElementById("content");

    const config = {
      filename: "test.pdf",
      image: { type: "png", quality: 0.5 },
      html2canvas: { dpi: 75, scale: 2, letterRendering: true },
      pagebreak: { mode: ["avoid-all", "css", "legacy"] },
      jsPDF: {
        orientation: "portrait",
        unit: "in",
        format: "a4",
        compressPDF: true,
      },
    };

    html2pdf()
      .from(content)
      .set(config)
      .toPdf()
      .get("pdf")
      .then((pdf) => {
        var totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
        for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
          pdf.setPage(i);
          pdf.addImage(watermarkImg, "png", 0.2, 0.6, 0, 0, undefined, "FAST", 45);
        }
        pdf.save();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error occurred during PDF generation:", error);
      });
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div id="content">
        {/* Your HTML content here */}
        <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleExportToPdf}>Generate PDF</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```